# Pass a column of a 2D array in Scala (or in Java)

Tags: java, arrays, scala

if we have an array in scala like
val myArray = myObject(N)(M)

it is very easy to pass a row of that array to a function just like this:

myFunction(myArray(i))

Is it possible to pass a column instead of a row? Or do I have to copy all elements of that row to a new 1d array and to pass that array?

Comment: I have a tuple collection framework that allows you to extract columns and has type safety advantages:  [product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also for any given 2D array, for instance

```
val a = Array.tabulate(2,3){_+2*_}
Array(Array(0, 2, 4), Array(1, 3, 5))
```

apply transposition and then fetch a column in the same way as with rows,

```
val t = a.transpose
Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 3), Array(4, 5))
```

and

```
t(1)
Array(2, 3)
```

which gives the second column.

Answer (score 3):

You have to copy all the elements, if you are restricted to just using an array.  If you use a wrapped version of an array, you can of course wrap it different ways, including with something that just travels down a column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` (creates a temporary copy) as in:

```
scala> val arr = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))
arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))

scala> arr(1) // row 1
res0: Array[Int] = Array(3, 4)

scala> arr map (_(1))  // col 1
res1: Array[Int] = Array(2, 4)
```